# Facebook Places for Android

Tags: android, facebook

If user Logged in the Facebook i want to get the Nearest Places available for that user similar to Four Square. And also i want to use  Check-ins options for a user..

I update my facebook with latest version and logged in it.. If i try to use Places option i am getting a message "THIS FEATURE WILL BE AVAILABLE IN YOUR REGION SOON.THANKS FOR YOUR PATIENCE"..Currently i am in INDIA-TamilNadu (Madurai)..

I don't want to use Foursquare API to implement this.. I want to know whether any API available in FACEBOOK to get this option..

Also i want to know for what Locations Places options available and whether its available for my location..

Give me some useful link to research about this and implement this using Facebook..

Thanks.. Venkatesh

Comment: I think the reason for your error message is that Facebook has not yet activated the Checkins feature in your country yet.  When they first activated it, it only worked in the United States. Then a few weeks later, they activated it in the UK. They have been adding more countries very slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Android, but what you want to research is using the Facebook Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

What you are interested in is referred to as checkins.  To find nearby places you would use a search see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Comment: What's the meaning for the error message i am getting?Its not avail in Location?

Comment: I can't really help with that. You will get better response directing that question to a place that focuses on the facebook api.